# Can't send socket with useNavigate hook

Tags: reactjs, socket.io, react-router-dom

##### Problem description

I'm using the `useNavigate` hook from `react-router-dom` to send data after redirecting the user, and I'm getting it with the `useLocation` hook. It works well when I'm sending ordinary data that I got from my form. But If I try to send the **socket** as well, it returns null for the **WHOLE** state. (I'm using scoket.io).

##### Code and output if I only send name and room

```
  const [name, setName] = useState();
  const [room, setRoom] = useState();
  const [socket, setSocket] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    const newSocket = io(`http://${window.location.hostname}:3001`);
    setSocket(newSocket);
    return () => newSocket.close();
  }, [setSocket]);

  const navigate = useNavigate();

  const joinRoom = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (name !== "" && room !== "") {
      socket.emit("join_room", { room: room, name: name });
      navigate("/chats", {
        state: { name: name, room: room },
      });
    }
  };
```

[image]

##### Code and output if I send name,room,socket

```
const [name, setName] = useState();
  const [room, setRoom] = useState();
  const [socket, setSocket] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    const newSocket = io(`http://${window.location.hostname}:3001`);
    setSocket(newSocket);
    return () => newSocket.close();
  }, [setSocket]);

  const navigate = useNavigate();

  const joinRoom = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (name !== "" && room !== "") {
      socket.emit("join_room", { room: room, name: name });
      navigate("/chats", {
        state: { name: name, room: room, socket: socket },
      });
    }
  };
```

[image]

Comment: From what I understand you can only send serializable data in route state. You may need to lift this `socket` state higher in the ReactTree so it's accessible in both app locations.

Comment: I see.  I might create a global state with the `context API`. Thank you!